# Save 128 bit value (unsigned) when max data type has 64 bits

Tags: c, unix

I have to save the number of non zero entries in a matrix with dimensions that could be
as big as `uint64_t` x `uint64_t` resulting in a `128 bit` value.

Im not sure which data-type would be right for this variable in `C` as it would require 128 bits (unsigned).

I would use `__int128` as a data type but my problem is that when I test the max. supported data type on my system with

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    printf("maxUInt: %lu\n", sizeof(uintmax_t));
    printf("maxInt: %lu", sizeof(intmax_t));
}
```

It gives the following result:

```
maxUInt: 8
maxInt: 8
```

meaning that 8 Bytes is the maximum for number representation.

So this is troubling me as the result is possibly 128 bits == 16 Bytes big.

Will `__int128` still work in my case?

Comment: AFAIK `sizeof(uintmax_t) = 8`  means that the `sizeof` of the largest **PRIMITIVE** data type is 8, but `__int128` is a gcc extension (not a primitive data type), does `int main(void) { __int128 x = 0; printf("%zu\n", sizeof x); }` compiles and print `16`? Then it works.

Comment: @DavidRanieri interesting. Thank you! Yes it printed 16 thankfully.

Comment: @David Ranieri, `__int128` is a primitive type. "Primitive" doesn't mean "in the standard" as you seem to think it does.

Comment: @ikegami but his answer that when it print 16 it works is still correct?

Comment: He said `uintmax_t` isn't the same as `unsigned __int128` because `__int128` isn't a primitive type, but that's wrong because it is a primitive type. (I don't claim to know the correct reason.) /// But of course `sizeof __int128` prints 16. That has nothing to do with the reason why `uintmax_t` isn't `unsigned __int128`.

Comment: @ikegami thats what I tought, how can I get more information about that?, all references I read on the net say something like _The primitive data types in c language are the inbuilt data types provided by the c language itself._ and there is no mention to the word "primitive" in the standard, do you have any quote?

Comment: @David Ranieri, Sometimes, languages use words in ways that differ from the norm. But the C standard doesn't use the word primitive, so this is not the case. A [primitive data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) is a basic type, one that isn't composed of other values. So int, char or float are primitives, but not a struct. It would include a pointer or reference, but not an object accessed via a reference (e.g. a JS array isn't a primitive type). The way I see it, if you can put it in hardware registers, it's a primitive data type. If you can't, it's not.

Comment: Since primitive data types can't be formed from other types, they are necessarily built-in. But that doesn't mean they are in the standard.

Comment: What is wrong with two `uint64_t` for line and column? You can't use c bultin arrays anyway.

Comment: @HAL9000 The array has dimensions with saved in uint64_t. meaning max number of elements is uint64_t * uint64_t

Comment: @stht55. No, you cannot have 2^128 number of elements. Even if you assign every atom in the universe to store the value of one element, you can not have that many elements, there is simply not enough atoms. The only way to work with such an array is to implement a sparse array, or some other compression scheme. None of those demand that you have a index of 128 bits. Having a c-array with an index that is wider that the pointer data type doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

One portable option is to construct a counter out of multiple smaller units:

```
typedef struct BigCounterC {
    uint64_t count_[2];
} BigCounterC;

void BigCounterC_increment(BigCounterC* counter) {
    // Increment the higher units when the lower unit of unsigned type wraps around reaching 0.
    for(size_t n = sizeof counter->count_ / sizeof *counter->count_; n-- && !++counter->count_[n];);
}

int main() {
    BigCounterC c2 = {0}; // Zero-initialize.
    BigCounterC_increment(&c2);
    return 0;
}
```

---

C++ version:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template<class Unit, size_t N>
struct BigCounter {
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned_v<Unit>); // Unsigned overflow is well defined.
    Unit count_[N] = {}; // Zero-initialize.

    BigCounter& operator++() noexcept {
        // Increment the higher units when the lower unit of unsigned type wraps around reaching 0.
        for(auto n = N; n-- && !++count_[n];);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    BigCounter<uint64_t, 2> c;
    ++c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We're talking about the size of an array, so `uintmax_t` and `intmax_t` are irrelevant.

`malloc()` accepts a `size_t`. The following therefore computes the limit of how much you can request:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

printf( "2^( %zu * %d ) bytes\n", sizeof( size_t ), CHAR_BIT );
```

For me, that's 2^( 8 * 8 ) octets.

18,446,744,073,709,551,616

But I'm an an x86-64 machine. Those don't support nearly that much memory. The instruction set only supports 2^48 octets of memory.

281,474,976,710,656   (1/65,536 of what 64 bits can support)

But no x86-64 machine supports that much. Current hardware only supports 2^40 octets of memory.

1,099,511,627,776 (1/16,777,216 of what 64 bits can support)

So unless you have some very special hardware, 64 bits is more than enough to store the size of any array your machine can handle.

---

Still, let's answer your question about support for `__int128` and `unsigned __int128`. These two types, if supported, are an extension to the standard. And they are apparently not candidates for `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`, at least on my compiler. So checking the size of `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` is not useful for detecting their support.

If you want to check if you have support for `__int128` or `unsigned __int128`, simply try to use them.

```c
__int128          i = 0;
unsigned __int128 u = 0;
```

If both `uintmax_t` and `unsigned __int128` are too small, you can still use extended precision math, such as by using two 64-bit integers in the manner showed in [Maxim Egorushkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72972048/589924).

Comment: Big datasets often get loaded and processed in pieces. Which means you can process a dataset and collect its statistics even if it doesn't fit into your RAM.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin For sure there are solutions. But the question wasn't about how to handle extremely large data sets. The OP was worried that they wouldn't be able allocate large arrays because of the size of `uintmax_t`. The point I'm making is that they have other problems they need to face first. And the solutions for those problems (for dealing with extremely large data sets) will make this problem moot.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention how matrix is allocated and stored, if I read correctly.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin I suppose you're right. In which case, it might be that only the second part of answer is relevant.

Comment: Well, using `size_t` for array and matrix dimensions suggests `size_t` by `size_t` maximum theoretical element count. Which is 64-bit by 64-bit on a 64-bit platform.